# PHP read links from .txt list anc check them if they are up

Tags: php, file

I'm new with .php and I can't make my code work. I have a function that checks if a website is up or down (that works), after that I just try to get link from a .txt file and echo them with the result from check function but I don't seem to get it right. Here is my code:

```html
<?php

function url_test( $url ) {
  $timeout = 10;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
  $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_respond = trim( strip_tags( $http_respond ) );
  $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
  if ( ( $http_code == "200" ) || ( $http_code == "302" ) ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // return $http_code;, possible too
    return false;
  }
  curl_close( $ch );
}


$links = file("test.txt");
if( !url_test( $links) ) {
  echo $links ." is down!";
}
else { echo $links ." functions correctly."; }
}


?>
```

Can you guys please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update of your code, this means that you have one url per line.

Hope this helps, happy coding.

```
<?php

function url_test( $url ) {
  $timeout = 10;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
  $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_respond = trim( strip_tags( $http_respond ) );
  $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
  if ( ( $http_code == "200" ) || ( $http_code == "302" ) ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // return $http_code;, possible too
    return false;
  }
  curl_close( $ch );
}


$file ="test.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the url
         if(url_test(trim($line))){
             print "Url $line Up\n";
         }else{
             print "Url $line Down\n";
         }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file("test.txt"); reads all lines of the file into an array.
If you know your file will always have only one line, you have to read the element of array at index 0 like this:

```
$links = file("test.txt");
if( !url_test( $links[0]) ) {
  echo $links[0] ." is down!";
}
else { 
  echo $links[0] ." functions correctly."; 
}
```

But if your file may contain a list of multiple URLs (one per line) then you'd have to loop through the array and check all of them like this:

```
$links = file("test.txt");
foreach ($links as $line_num => $link) {
  if( !url_test( $link) ) {
    echo $link ." is down!";
  }
  else { 
    echo $link ." functions correctly."; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I will have multiple URLs (one per line). I did try your solution but it does not anything

Comment: I copied your code which had too many curly braces. The code is cleaned now and should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `file()` will return an array of lines, so if you have just one URL in the file you can use `[0]` to pass the first line, otherwise pass in the list and use `foreach()`.  It's also worth using `trim()` to ensure that the URL is clear of any stray spaces etc when setting the URL.  I've also changed the test to check if the status code is in a set of possible acceptable statuses rather than checking individual values.

Multi URL code...

```
function url_test( $url ) {
    $timeout = 10;
    $ch = curl_init();
    foreach ( $url as $link )   {
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($link) );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
        $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
        if ( !in_array($http_code , ["200", "301", "302"] ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    curl_close( $ch );
    return true;
}

$links = file("test.txt");
if( !url_test( $links) ) {
    echo " is down!";
}
else { echo " functions correctly."; }
```

1 URL example...

```
function url_test( $url ) {
    $timeout = 10;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url) );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    if ( !in_array($http_code , ["200", "301", "302"] ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    curl_close( $ch );
    return true;
}


$links = file("test.txt");
if( !url_test( $links[0]) ) {
    echo " is down!";
}
else { echo " functions correctly."; }
```